# Asynchronousity does not work with CompletableFuture

Tags: java

I want to make an async call with `CompletableFuture` :

```
public void sendTrameToSAGE(String trameAbsPathName, List<Object> ids, String src) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    File trame = new File(trameAbsPathName);
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFutureCopy = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            File destination = new File("\\\\"+env.getProperty("dossier.distant.interfacage.sage1000.mode.local")+"\\retour");
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(trame, destination);
            return "OK";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("======================== erreur envoi distant < ioexception > = "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "NOK";
        } catch(Exception x) {
            System.out.println("======================== erreur envoi distant < exception > = "+x.getMessage());
            x.printStackTrace();
            return "NOK";
        }
    });
    while (!completableFutureCopy.isDone()) {
            
    }
    if (completableFutureCopy.get().equals("OK")) {
        marquerIntervs(interfassageIntervsCloturer, ids);
        trame.delete();
    }
}
```

At runtime the file is already deleted before it is copied to the destination folder ! So what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: code runs in my environment without problem

Comment: Note you shouldn't spin wait (the `while (!isDone)` loop). If you want to wait for the future to complete you can use `join()` or `get()`; they both block until the future completes.